# pass value from controller and view in html file

Tags: angularjs, controller

I am trying to pass value from controller and show it in html file using angularjs but unable to achieve it. I am using metronic angularjs theme and implementing easypie charts on dashboard and want to pass value to that using controller.

This is **app.js** file:

````
var MetronicApp = angular.module("MetronicApp", [
    "ui.router",
    "ui.bootstrap",
    "oc.lazyLoad",
    "ngSanitize",
    'ngCookies'
]);

MetronicApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
});

MetronicApp.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
});

/* Configure ocLazyLoader(refer: https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) */
MetronicApp.config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider', function($ocLazyLoadProvider) {
    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        cssFilesInsertBefore: 'ng_load_plugins_before' // load the above css files before a LINK element with this ID. Dynamic CSS files must be loaded between core and theme css files
    });
}]);

/********************************************
 BEGIN: BREAKING CHANGE in AngularJS v1.3.x:
*********************************************/
/**
`$controller` will no longer look for controllers on `window`.
The old behavior of looking on `window` for controllers was originally intended
for use in examples, demos, and toy apps. We found that allowing global controller
functions encouraged poor practices, so we resolved to disable this behavior by
default.

To migrate, register your controllers with modules rather than exposing them
as globals:

Before:

```javascript
function MyController() {
    // ...
}
```

After:

```javascript
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyController', [function() {
    // ...
}]);

Although it's not recommended, you can re-enable the old behavior like this:

```javascript
angular.module('myModule').config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
    // this option might be handy for migrating old apps, but please don't use it
    // in new ones!
    $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);
**/

MetronicApp.factory('authInterceptor', ['$q', '$window', '$injector', function($q, $window, $injector) {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if ($window.localStorage.token) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.localStorage.token;
            }
            return config;
        },
        response: function(response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                // handle the case where the user is not authenticated
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function(rejection) {
            if (rejection.status == 401) {
                var $state = $injector.get("$state");
                $state.go('login')
                    // location.reload();
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
}]);

MetronicApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
}]);


//AngularJS v1.3.x workaround for old style controller declarition in HTML
MetronicApp.config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
    // this option might be handy for migrating old apps, but please don't use it
    // in new ones!
    $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);

/********************************************
 END: BREAKING CHANGE in AngularJS v1.3.x:
*********************************************/

/* Setup App Main Controller */
MetronicApp.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        Metronic.initComponents(); // init core components
        //Layout.init(); //  Init entire layout(header, footer, sidebar, etc) on page load if the partials included in server side instead of loading with ng-include directive 
    });
}]);

/***
Layout Partials.
By default the partials are loaded through AngularJS ng-include directive. In case they loaded in server side(e.g: PHP include function) then below partial 
initialization can be disabled and Layout.init() should be called on page load complete as explained above.
***/

/* Setup Layout Part - Header */
MetronicApp.controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
        Layout.initHeader(); // init header
    });
}]);

/* Setup Layout Part - Sidebar */
MetronicApp.controller('SidebarController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
        Layout.initSidebar(); // init sidebar
    });
}]);

/* Setup Layout Part - Sideba
r */
MetronicApp.controller('PageHeadController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
        Demo.init(); // init theme panel
    });
}]);

/* Setup Layout Part - Footer */
MetronicApp.controller('FooterController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
        Layout.initFooter(); // init footer
    });
}]);

/* Setup Rounting For All Pages */
MetronicApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // Redirect any unmatched url
    $urlRouterProvider
        .otherwise(function($injector, $location) {
            // This function prevents  the infinite loop on otherwise while session wasn't found
            var $state = $injector.get("$state");
            $state.go("home");
        });

    $stateProvider

        .state('app', {
            url: "/app/",
            templateUrl: "static/html/tpl/app.html"
        })
        // Dashboard
        .state('app.dashboard', {
            url: "dashboard",
            templateUrl: "static/html/views/dashboard.html",
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Dashboard'
                // pageSubTitle: 'statistics & reports'
            },
            requireLogin: true,
            controller: "DashboardController",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'MetronicApp',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                        files: [
                            'static/assets/global/plugins/morris/morris.css',
                            'static/assets/admin/pages/css/tasks.css',
                            'static/assets/global/plugins/morris/morris.min.js',
                            'static/assets/global/plugins/morris/raphael-min.js',
                            'static/assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular.min.js',
                            'static/assets/global/plugins/jquery-easypiechart/jquery.easypiechart.min.js',
                            'static/assets/global/plugins/jquery.sparkline.min.js',
                            'static/assets/admin/pages/scripts/index3.js',
                            'static/assets/admin/pages/scripts/tasks.js',
                            'static/js/controllers/DashboardController.js'
                        ]
                    });
                }]
            }
        })

        .state('home', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "static/html/views/login.html",
        controller: "LoginController",
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                    name: 'MetronicApp',
                    insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before',
                    files: [
                        'static/assets/admin/pages/css/login-soft.css',
                        'static/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                        'static/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js',
                        'static/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
                        'static/assets/global/plugins/backstretch/jquery.backstretch.min.js',
                        'static/assets/admin/pages/scripts/login-soft.js',
                        'static/js/controllers/AccessController.js',
                        'static/js/services/AccessService.js',
                        'static/js/services/CommonService.js'
                    ]
                }]);
            }]
        }
    })

    // .state('home', {
    //  url: "/home",
    //  // controller:"HomeController"
    //  templateUrl: "views/home.html",
    //  resolve: {
    //      deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
    //          return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
    //              name: 'MetronicApp',
    //              files: [
    //                  'js/controllers/HomeController.js'
    //              ]
    //          }]);
    //      }]
    //  }
    // })

    // .state('login', {
    //  url: "/login",
    //  templateUrl: "views/login.html",
    //  controller: "LoginController",
    //  resolve: {
    //      deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
    //          return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
    //              name: 'MetronicApp',
    //              insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before',
    //              files: [
    //                  '../assets/admin/pages/css/login-soft.css',
    //                  '../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    //                  '../assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js',
    //                  '../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    //                  '../assets/global/plugins/backstretch/jquery.backstretch.min.js',
    //                  '../assets/admin/pages/scripts/login-soft.js',
    //                  'js/controllers/AccessController.js',
    //                  'js/services/AccessService.js',
    //                  'js/services/CommonService.js'
    //              ]
    //          }]);
    //      }]
    //  }
    // })

    .state('signup', {
        url: "/signup",
        templateUrl: "static/html/views/signup.html",
        controller: "SignupController",
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                    name: 'MetronicApp',
                    insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before',
                    files: [
                        'static/assets/admin/pages/css/login-soft.css',
                        'static/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                        'static/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js',
                        'static/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
                        'static/assets/global/plugins/backstretch/jquery.backstretch.min.js',
                        'static/assets/admin/pages/scripts/login-soft.js',
                        'static/js/controllers/AccessController.js',
                        'static/js/services/AccessService.js',
                        'static/js/services/CommonService.js'
                    ]
                }]);
            }]
        }
    })

    .state('forget-password', {
            url: "/forget-password",
            templateUrl: "static/html/views/forget-password.html",
            controller: "ForgetPasswordController",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                        name: 'MetronicApp',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before',
                        files: [
                            'static/assets/admin/pages/css/login-soft.css',
                            'static/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                            'static/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js',
                            'static/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
                            'static/assets/global/plugins/backstretch/jquery.backstretch.min.js',
                            'static/assets/admin/pages/scripts/login-soft.js',
                            'static/js/controllers/AccessController.js',
                            'static/js/services/AccessService.js',
                            'static/js/services/CommonService.js'
                        ]
                    }]);
                }]
            }
        })
        // AngularJS plugins
        .state('fileupload', {
            url: "/file_upload.html",
            templateUrl: "static/html/views/file_upload.html",
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'AngularJS File Upload',
                pageSubTitle: 'angularjs file upload'
            },
            controller: "GeneralPageController",
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                        name: 'angularFileUpload',
                        files: [
                            'static/assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.min.js',
                        ]
                    }, {
                        name: 'MetronicApp',
                        files: [
                            'static/js/controllers/GeneralPageController.js'
                        ]
                    }]);
                }]
            }
        })

    // UI Select
    .state('uiselect', {
        url: "/ui_select.html",
        templateUrl: "static/html/views/ui_select.html",
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'AngularJS Ui Select',
            pageSubTitle: 'select2 written in angularjs'
        },
        controller: "UISelectController",
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                    name: 'ui.select',
                    insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                    files: [
                        'static/assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/ui-select/select.min.css',
                        'static/assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/ui-select/select.min.js'
                    ]
                }, {
                    name: 'MetronicApp',
                    files: [
                        'static/js/controllers/UISelectController.js'
                    ]
                }]);
            }]
        }
    })

}]);

/* Init global settings and run the app */
MetronicApp
    .service('AuthenticateService', ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$window', function($http, $cookieStore, $window) {
        this.isLoggedIn = function() {
            if (!$cookieStore.get('JU_user_logged') || $cookieStore.get('JU_user_logged') == false || !$window.localStorage.token) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            };
        };
    }])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'AuthenticateService', '$window',
        function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, AuthenticateService, $window) {
            $rootScope.$state = $state;
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
                if (toState.name != 'login' && !AuthenticateService.isLoggedIn() && toState.requireLogin) {
                    $state.go('login');
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    ])
````

This is my **DashboardController** through which I want to pass value:-

```
'use strict';

MetronicApp.controller('DashboardController', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {   
        // initialize core components
        Metronic.initAjax();
    });
    $scope.steps = 1000;

});
```

This is the **dashboard.html** file:-

```
<ul class="page-breadcrumb breadcrumb hide">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        Dashboard
    </li>
</ul>

<div ng-controller="DashboardController" class="margin-top-10">
    <h1>**{{ steps }}** </h1>
    <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="portlet light ">
                            <div class="portlet-title">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <i class="icon-cursor font-purple-intense hide"></i>
                                    <span class="caption-subject font-purple-intense bold uppercase">Tracker Report</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="actions">
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-circle btn-default easy-pie-chart-reload">
                                    <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i> Reload </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="portlet-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="easy-pie-chart">
                                        <div class="number transactions" data-percent="55">
                                            <span>{{ steps }}</span>
                                        </div>

                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="margin-bottom-10 visible-sm">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="easy-pie-chart">
                                        <div class="number visits" data-percent="85">
                                            <span>
                                            +85 </span>
                                            %
                                        </div>

                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="margin-bottom-10 visible-sm">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="easy-pie-chart">
                                        <div class="number bounce" data-percent="46">
                                            <span>
                                            +46 </span>
                                            %
                                        </div>

                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="margin-bottom-10 visible-sm">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="easy-pie-chart">
                                        <div class="number bounce" data-percent="32">
                                            <span>
                                            +32 </span>
                                            %
                                        </div>

                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: @ddepablo nope. while loading html file it is showing {{ steps }} as a variable. Unable to fetch value from controller i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've changed the interpolate symbol in your app.js file:

```
MetronicApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
});
```

It means that ,in your templates, you need to replace:

```
<h1>**{{ steps }}** </h1>
```

to

```
<h1>**{$ steps $}** </h1>
```

Or to remove the lines in your app.js file to keep the default interpolate symbol.